# Unable to access Ubuntu Server from Internet

Tags: networking, apache2, webserver, wordpress

I have set up an Ubuntu Server on which I have installed WordPress.The domain name  is pointing to my ISP Public IP.I am able to access the internet from my Server.
I am also able to access the website on the same LAN however when i try to access the website from a different network it says "this Site cannot be reached".My domain name is resolving to the correct IP.
Kindly let me know where i am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you forwarded the appropriate ports in your router to the computer with your web server?

Comment: in my router i have allowed only port 80.

Comment: What you mean allowed? There must have page called "Forwarding" or something similar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgUOj.png

Comment: yeah thats what i mean i forwarded port 80 on my router...thanks